# How to avoid duplicates while inserting the contacts into android 2.2?

Tags: android

How to avoid the duplicates while inserting the contacts into android 2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a lookup for the contact first? Also, note that Android will try to aggregate contacts with similar characteristics.